Mocking throws iterable issue but not suggesting to resolve
This is the main python class and its methods
class ParserManner():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.file_path = kwargs.get(‘file_path’, None)
        self.soup = kwargs.get(‘soup’, None)
        self.observations = []
        self.ap_path = kwargs.get(‘ap_path’, ‘testy/ap.xml’)
        self.plugin_map_path = kwargs.get(‘plugin_map_path’, ‘testy’/plugin_map.csv’)
    
    @classmethod
    def load(self, file_name) -> Self:
        file_path = None
        try:
            somecode here
            except:
                raise RuntimeError(“Unable to load soup”)
            
            return ParserManner(file_path=file_path, soup=soup)


    def parse(self, soup) -> [Orange]:
        try:
        except:
        ....


This below is a pytest methods created to test the above class:
step 1 first create a setup method
def setup_instance():
    instance = myClass()
    instance.ap_path = 'some_path'
    instance.plugin_map_path = 'some_path'
    instance.file_path = 'some_path'
    instance.observations = []
    return instance

step 2 define a test method:
def test_open_file_success():
    with patch('builtins.open', mock_open(read_data='<assessment-plan></assessment-plan>')) as mock_file:
        instance = setup_instance()
        instance.parse(Mock())
        mock_file.assert_called_once_with('some_path', 'r')

pytesst => running this code throws " TypeError: 'Mock' object is not iterable"
any idea?


Can you explain what you are trying to do?

running this code throws Mock object is not iterable error and don't know what should I do to make that work

I understand the error you're getting.  I'm trying to understand what you are attempting to DO.

You are not providing a callstack, so we can only guess where it crashes - probably in parse, but as you don't provide the relevant code either, it's impossible to say.

Only one advise, you can create temporary files with pytest, try this way instead mock open.
